# SQL ondelete cascade with join table

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have three tables in database `Notes`, `Tags`, `NoteTagJoin` I'm using `many to many` database relation with foreign keys which are stored in `NoteTagJoin` table now I know that you can set for foreign keys `onCascade delete` and as far as I know if I would delete `Note` all `Tags` and `NoteTagJoin` references would be deleted associated with this `Note`, but is there any way to do so that only from `Notes` entries would be deleted and references from `NoteTagJoin` but not from `Tags` because other notes can have same tags using onCascade delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution which comes to mind for me would be to just use `ON DELETE CASCADE` with the bridge table `NoteTagJoin`.  Then, deleting notes from the `Notes` table would remove the note-tag associations, but would not remove anything from the `Tags` table.

This leaves the problem of possibly dangling tags which are not associated with any notes.  But maybe you could run a periodic cleanup job to remove those, or perhaps these would be managed manually by someone (e.g. an app).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can

```
ALTER TABLE `notes_tags` 
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`note_id`) REFERENCES `notes` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE ;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hU2nuUrSiujYtn9eBtuXV/0)